# LaraCSV export error ( Because of big data)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, export-csv

I have this code in my laravel project which creates and downloads CSV from Laravel Query
 `$csvExporter->build($example_users, $example_headers, array('header'=>true))->download($fileName);`
But i am getting internal error because the $example_users table is too big.
I know that there is some way to do it with chunks e.c (LaraCSV Repo) But can't configure out how.
Please help

Comment: what error code do you get?

Comment: "Internal Server Error" - The same code works fine when there is no big data. But when I am working on 96k rows ( Too much but there is no other way ) it stops working after like 30 seconds with - "Internal Server Error" Message

Comment: I am skeptical that this is a large data error, for this we have different HTTP code, anyway, chunk is one of the solutions for large data handling. I am sure you have already tried it, but here it is https://github.com/usmanhalalit/laracsv#build-by-chunks.
Alternatively, on top of my head, I will suggest you use a queue or multithread.

Comment: At this time I see this error: Argument 1 passed to Laracsv\Export::buildFromBuilder() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection givenArgument.

Comment: Now I am using buildFromBuilder() function. As I see my $example_users is a collection. So How can I change the code to make it eloquent/builder?